# Simple regex replace in R

Tags: regex, r

I am close but can't seem to get this to work. I'd like to achieve converting this string "1960-12-**031** 22:00:**010**" to this string "1960-12-**31** 22:00:**10**" by finding the places where two numbers are preceded by a 0 and then stripping the 0.

I've got the regex working:

```
txt <- "1960-12-031 22:00:010"
gsub("(0+[0-9]{2})", "\\1", txt, perl=TRUE)
```

I just can't seem to figure out what to do with the "\\1" to strip out the first character.

Any assistance would be appreciated -

Comment: I don't think there should be a + after the first zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt <- "1960-12-031 22:00:010"
gsub("0+([0-9]{2})", "\\1", txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Note that this will replace 031, 0031, 00031, etc. with 31. If you want to remove only the first zero, use `"0{1}([0-9]{2})"`.

Update: As per the recommendation in the comment you can use `"[\\D]0+([0-9]{2})"` to avoid matching zeros within numbers such as 2012.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I really appreciate you taking the time for a newbie regex question.

Comment: It will also replace (the year) 2012 with 212, so you could consider using and catching `-` or `:`  in your pattern: `gsub("([:-])0([0-9]{2})", "\\1\\2", txt, perl=TRUE)`